# Medusa.js backend admin blank page

Tags: medusajs, medusa

I running both storefront starter template and backend admin medusa.js.

Frontend template working correct.

When I curl for admin backend, I see only:

```
[root@vim1999 ~]# curl http://localhost:7001

<title>Medusa</title> <script defer src="/runtime~main.bundle.js"></script><script defer src="/main.bundle.js"></script>
[root@vim1999 ~]#
```

When I curl for storefront, I correct see full layout page.

For test Both I set proxy reverse to domain and now `domain.com` store front working perfect. But when I access to `domain.com/admin` I see blank page. of course in browser code inspection visible above code from curl.

Medusa server is turned on correctly and does not return any errors. `ngnix, Node 18`.

Browser admin console inspection return this:
[preview image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk2pM.png)